# How to determine whether T is a value type or reference class in generic?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic method behavior of which depends on T is reference type or value type. It looks so:

```
T SomeGenericMethod <T> (T obj)
{
  if (T is class) //What condition I must write in the brackets?
   //to do one stuff
  else //if T is a value type like struct, int, enum and etc.
   //to do another stuff
}
```

I can't duplicate this method like:

```
T SomeGenericMethod <T> (T obj) where T : class
{
 //Do one stuff
}

T SomeGenericMethod <T> (T obj) where T : struct
{
 //Do another stuff
}
```

because their signatures are equal. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use the [`typeof` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) with generic types, so `typeof(T)` will get the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42892f65.aspx) reference corresponding to `T`, and then use the [`IsValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx) property:

```
if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
```

Or if you want to include nullable value types as if they were reference types:

```
// Only true if T is a reference type or nullable value type
if (default(T) == null)
```

Comment: Thank you for your additional explanation on nullable value types.

Comment: The second option is a possible comparison of a value type with null, which is something ReSharper likes to bark about.  Is there any way around that?

Comment: In optimization scenarios do keep in mind that the call is translated to constant by newer JITs, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/1157.

Answer (score 7):

`Type.IsValueType` tells, naturally, if `Type` is a value type. Hence, `typeof(T).IsValueType`.

Answer (score 7):

[The following answer does not check the *static* type of `T` but the *dynamic* type of `obj`. This is not *exactly* what you asked for, but since it might be useful for your problem anyway, I'll keep this answer for reference.]

All value types (and only those) derive from [`System.ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx). Thus, the following condition can be used:

```
if (obj is ValueType) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: T is a type, not an expression, so you can't use `is`. Also, consider where `T` is exactly System.ValueType, which is a reference type...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks, good point, changed to `obj is ValueType`. Since `ValueType` is an abstract class, `obj` cannot be exactly `ValueType` (of course, this assumes that `obj` is not null... I'll add that to my answer).

Comment: That doesn't tell you about `T`. Consider `SomeGenericMethod<int?>(null)` - `int?` is a value type, but your condition won't match.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I just realized the same thing and added it to my answer. As always, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Of course I've also realised that it would report the wrong thing for `SomeGenericMethod<object>(1)` as well - your edit explains that situation too.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the party, but I just stumbled on this.
So as of determining if it's a Reference-Type,

```
typeof(T).IsClass
```

respectively

```
obj.GetType().IsClass
```

could work (.net 4.7+ , not checked on former Versions)

Comment: I think this fails on the interface types, which are clearly references, but IsClass returns false