# Passing by Reference vs Value

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I was scrolling through the MySQL connector code for .NET Core.

I saw the following code:

```
public async Task DeleteAsync
{
    var cmd = Db.Connection.CreateCommand() as MySqlCommand;
    cmd.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM `BlogPost` WHERE `Id` = @id;";
    BindId(cmd);
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}

private void BindId(MySqlCommand cmd)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@id",
        DbType = DbType.Int32,
        Value = Id,
    });
}
```

Wouldn't this cause the method call

```
await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

to be parameterless?

Full code on
https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/tutorials/net-core-mvc/

Comment: Since the `BindId(cmd);` is not using ref nor out isn't it being passed by value ?

Comment: No, MySqlCommand is not struct for it to be passed by value

Comment: I thought everything was passed as value unless otherwise stated. Could you post as an answer all the cases where data is passed as reference instead of value without using the `out` or `ref` operators ?

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks ! Found this answer that helps me find which are reference types : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580288/how-to-determine-whether-t-is-a-value-type-or-reference-class-in-generic

Comment: [A diagram by way of explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251645/1968)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about how the passing semantics work in C#. You have probably heard that C#, by default, always pass variables by value which is correct. However, C# has two different types of variables: [*value types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) and [*reference types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

If `MySqlCommand` was a value type (a struct), you would have been correct in your assumption that it would be copied into the `BindId` method. However, `MySqlCommand` is a class and therefore a reference type.

When you pass a reference type to a method, C# creates a *copy of the reference* to the object in memory. So the reference in `BindId` still references the same `MySqlCommand` object in memory.

I hope this makes sense. I recommend reading some of the official documentation on the subject:

[Passing Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)

Comment: Yeah, that was my confusion, feeling really dumb right now, and have a lot of code that makes no sense after knowing this...
Classes, interfaces, objects and are all reference types and structs and enumerators are value types.

Comment: No reason to feel dumb. It's a subject that is often misunderstood. :)

Comment: I hate to add a "me, too" but this cannot be emphasized enough. You knew enough to determine exactly why the actual behavior was different from what you expected. That enables you ask the question, get the answer, and add it to what you know. That's exactly what everyone keeps doing every day. It's okay to *feel* dumb - just don't ever believe it.

Answer (score 1):

It is passing a *reference* to the command (because it is a **reference-type**, i.e. an object) as the parameter/argument, and that reference is being passed by value, i.e. a separate copy **of the reference**. But: that's basically just like copying a pointer: any copy of the pointer still points to the same location, and thus a copy of a reference still points to the same object. Any changes to the object will be visible to all consumers, that have a copy of the same reference.

The only relevance of "by value" here is that if the `BindId` method *assigns a new value to `cmd`*, then that *assignment to a different object* won't be visible to the caller - the caller will still only know about the *original* command object.

Answer (score 0):

.Net has 2 fundamental types. Reference and value types.

Reference type values itself resides in the heap, **but reference of that value which point to the location of the heap itself resides in the stack**, when you pass reference value to the method CLR creates the copy of the that reference and pass that copy. But since it is reference, it still points to the original value.

Value types value itself resides in the stack and value types do not have references. When you pass value type to the method CLR creates the copy of that value and pass it. And if you would do some operations with that value original would not be corrupted. From John Skeet's blog

Suppose we have printed pages about countries list and web site which contains the same info as printed pages.

*The information would be the same, but the two media types behave in different ways. Printed pages have value semantics and web sites have reference semantics. In other words, printed pages act like value types and web sites act like reference types.The page contains the information directly. When you access a web page, you use a URL to get to it - in our example, the URL is analogous to a reference used to access a reference type object*.

Here is the link this is best explanation i have ever seen.

[Ref vs value types in .Net Jon Skeet](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html).